# How to remove comma from one row (first row) in write_delim?

Tags: r, tidyverse

How can I not write `,` after the date ( first row) in the following example data.

```
library(tidyverse)
dt <- structure(list(
  tmax = c(1990101, 5.974, 6.15, 5.806, 5.694),
  tmin = c(NA, 0.5, 0.475, -0.083, 0.944)
), row.names = c(NA,
                 -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
write_delim(
  dt,
  file = "test_comma.txt",
  delim = ",",
  append = F,
  na = "",
  col_names = F
)
```

How to remove the comma after date when saved as a text file. I want like in left on the image below.[image]

Comment: (1) Why use `write_delim` when you're writing CSV? `write_csv` seems more direct. (2) `system("sed -i -e '1 {s/,$//g;}' test_comma.txt")`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By using `append` and two separate write operations this can be done with using `sed` (not the first blank line in the file in your example I'm not sure if that is on intend otherwise adjust the `write_lines` statement):

```r
library(tidyverse)
dt <- structure(list(
  tmax = c(1990101, 5.974, 6.15, 5.806, 5.694),
  tmin = c(NA, 0.5, 0.475, -0.083, 0.944)
), row.names = c(NA,
                 -5L), class = c("tbl_df", "tbl", "data.frame"))
write_lines(c('',dt[1,1]),file = "test_comma.txt")
write_delim(
  dt[-1,],
  file = "test_comma.txt",
  delim = ",",
  append = T,
  na = "",
  col_names = F
)
```